# Is there a way to list apps by categories in Windows Store on Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-store

In Windows 8.1, the apps shown to me seem to be what the store thinks I should have, i.e.: "trending" & "editor's picks".

Is there a way to list the apps grouped by category? Or show a list of all categories?

[image]

I could've sworn there was an option to list all apps by categories on the main page in Windows 8, wondering how I can achieve that in Windows 8.1

Comment: You sure you are not recalling the store layout in Windows 8.0?  There were signifcant changes to the Windows Store layout.  Have you tried searching for an application, then selecting a result, and using clicking on a category that application was filed under?  There might be a better way but need access to my VM in order to determine that ( if I do I will post an answer ).

Comment: @Ramhound I can search & then follow the category, but that's a. too cumbersome & b. I don't necessarily know under which category a particular app is on. I realize I might be recalling Windows 8 layout, I kinda prefer that and would like to see that style. Updated question to make it more clear

Comment: Bingo.  Perhaps you can figure out how to access http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/W81-StoreMenu-Resize-640x98.jpg from http://www.extremetech.com/computing/168990-the-windows-8-1-store-much-improved-but-still-a-long-way-off-ios-and-android before I do.

Comment: Your question was clear.  Point blank they got rid of the Windows 8.0 layout and by default it will be what you posted although you can still shop by categories ( per the image ) i posted.  I just don't have access to a Win8 machine to post an actual answer :-(

Comment: @Ramhound found a way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok thanks to some random button & mouse click mashing, I found that right clicking on the Windows store page brings down a menu where you can select the category & sort preferences

[image]